# Python Univariate Linear Regression gives horizontal slope and high cost

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm doing an assignment on linear regression and I'm having trouble with my prediction slope. No matter what I do it comes out as a horizontal line. The cost also gets stuck at 908787 with no improvement. I followed the professor's functions as he wants this model coded by scratch. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
#Dataset Preparation
diabetes = load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data
Y = diabetes.target
```

```
# Use only one feature (BMI)
X = X[:, np.newaxis, 2]
X = X.reshape((-1,1))

Y = np.expand_dims(Y, 1)
data = np.append(X, Y, 1)

# random shuffle
np.random.seed(1201)
np.random.shuffle(data)

# split data
total_sample = len(data)
train = data[:int(total_sample*0.70)]
dev = data[int(total_sample*0.70):int(total_sample*0.85)]
test = data[int(total_sample*0.85):]
```

```
def get_features_and_labels(data):
  features = data[:,:-1]
  labels = data[:,-1]
  return features, labels

train_x, train_y = get_features_and_labels(train)
dev_x, dev_y = get_features_and_labels(dev)
test_x, test_y = get_features_and_labels(test)
```

```
# Linear Regression Model

def univariate_linear_regression(theta, input):
  pred = theta[0] + theta[1]*input
  return pred

# Cost Function
def compute_cost(Y_pred, Y_true):
  J = 1/(2*m) * np.sum((Y_pred - Y_true)**2) # Mean Square Error
  return J

def update_theta(theta, X, Y_true, Y_pred, lr):
  theta[0] = theta[0] - (lr * (1/m) * np.sum(Y_pred - Y_true))
  theta[1] = theta[1] - (lr * (1/m) * np.sum((Y_pred - Y_true) * X))
  return theta
```

```
theta = [0.0, 0.0]
lr = 0.0001
m = len(train_y)
k = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))

for i in range(500):
  pred = univariate_linear_regression(theta, train_x)
  cost = compute_cost(pred, train_y)
  theta = update_theta(theta, train_x, train_y, pred, lr)


  if(i%20==0):
    print(f"Iteration {i}, Cost: {cost}, Theta: {theta}")
    k +=1
    plt.subplot(5, 5, k)
    plt.scatter(train_x, train_y, color='b')
    plt.plot(train_x, pred, 'g')
```

```
    s = 'theta:[%.4f, %.4f]' %(theta[0], theta[1])
    c = 'cost: %.4f' %cost
    plt.title(s+'\n'+c)
```

Graph Output:

[image: Graph Output]

I tried playing around with the learning curve and initial theta but it still ends with the same result.

Comment: A useful check is to inspect the shapes of the variables and ensure they match your expectations, e.g. `print(X.shape)` etc.

Comment: Any luck with getting it to work?

Comment: I ended up scaling the training and test sets which helped a bunch. Couldn't get the cost down any lower than 1963, so that might be as good as it'll get.

Comment: I see. I think the root cause could be that `get_features_and_labels` wasn't returning `labels` as a column vector shaped `n_samples x 1`, causing a mismatch with `preds` that led to an erroneous calculation when they were subtracted at the update step. In the process of scaling you may have also transformed `train_y` to a column vector.